# Initialize a static const class member with no parameters in constructor of a custom class in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, initialization, member

How can I initialize a static const class member of a custom class in C++?

Here is what I tried so far:

Header file:

```
class A
{
private:
static const B b;
};
```

Source file:

```
const B A::b;
```

Class`s B constructor has no parameters.

The approach does not work. The `b` becomes red underlined in the source file and it is written over there `const member "A::b" requires an initializer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you provide a default constructor for B?

```
class B
{
public:
    B() {}
};
```

It worked here